# Unable to load .pem private key

Tags: java, configuration, pem

Can someone help to me to understand this error? Is is due to some configuration problem? Or is because the permissions are not properly set?

```
xyz@tatlo .globus]$ voms-proxy-init 
Credentials couldn't be loaded 
    [/mnt/t3nfs01/data01/shome/xyz/.globus/userkey.pem, 
     /mnt/t3nfs01/data01/shome/xyz/.globus/usercert.pem]: 
        Can not load the PEM private key: java.io.IOException: 
        Can not load the PEM private key: no input data (empty source?)
No credentials found!
[xyz@tatlo .globus]$ ls
mycert.p12  usercert.pem  userkey.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have configured VOMS server endpoints properly. Also, check if the credentials are in the correct directory. 
They should generally go into $HOME/.globus directory. Certificates encoded in PKCS12 and PEM formats are correctly handled by the VOMS clients. 
The default path for looking up PKCS12 credentials is:

$HOME/.globus/usercred.p12

Also, check the permissions set on the formats if not set accordingly. 
Permissions on $HOME/.globus/usercred.p12 must be 600.
For PEM credentials the following paths are used:

$HOME/.globus/usercert.pem (certificate)
$HOME/.globus/userkey.pem (private key)

Permissions on the pem files must be:

```
644 for $HOME/.globus/usercert.pem
400 for $HOME/.globus/userkey.pem
```

In case both the PEM and PKCS12 formats are present, PEM takes precedence.

Refer [link](http://italiangrid.github.io/voms/documentation/voms-clients-guide/3.0.3/) for more guidelines.

Comment: How do we exactly set the permissions in the command line. This link (https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder) talk about it a bit but I do not understand what is the exact format of the command to set up such a permission.

Comment: Permissions can be set by using command 'chmod' with combination of numbers say 644 (6-owner of the file can Read+Write, 4-usergroup can only read and 4-everyone can only read). This can be achieved using command "chmod 644 usercert.pem" and "chmod 400 userkey.pem" in our problem. Try to google it and check for many other options.